# Use package httr to get data from web API

Tags: r, bioinformatics, httr

I have been trying to access an online API for bioinformatic purposes.
The API was listed in their [website](http://tools.iedb.org/main/tools-api/) with examples using curl.
The examples they used is:

```
$ curl --data "method=smm&sequence_text=SLYNTVATLYCVHQRIDV&allele=HLA-A*01:01&length=9" http://tools-cluster-interface.iedb.org/tools_api/mhci/
```

Using an online unix terminal, I can get the correct output:
[Unix curl output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfAss.png)

I tried to setup an R script using httr:

```
library(httr)
url="http://tools-cluster-interface.iedb.org/tools_api/mhci/"
results=POST(url,body="method=smm&sequence_text=SLYNTVATLYCVHQRIDV&allele=HLA-A*01:01&length=9")
content(results,"text")
```

However, the results I got do not contain useful information

```
[1] "Available methods:\nann\ncomblib_sidney2008\nconsensus\nnetmhccons\nnetmhcpan\nnetmhcstabpan\npickpocket\nrecommended\nsmm\nsmmpmbec\n\n* Please go to the link below for usage info:\nhttp://tools.iedb.org/main/html/tools_api.html\n"
```

I just want to know 1) if my script is the correct way to reflect their API method with curl? 2) how to use their api in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used `curlconverter` to process the `curl` command line:

```
library(curlconverter)
library(httr)

curl_line <- 'curl --data "method=smm&sequence_text=SLYNTVATLYCVHQRIDV&allele=HLA-A*01:01&length=9" http://tools-cluster-interface.iedb.org/tools_api/mhci/'

straighten(curl_line) %>%
  make_req() -> req

req[[1]]
## function () 
## httr::VERB(verb = "POST", url = "http://tools-cluster-interface.iedb.org/tools_api/mhci/", 
##     body = list(method = "smm", sequence_text = "SLYNTVATLYCVHQRIDV", 
##         allele = "HLA-A*01:01", length = "9"))
## <environment: 0x7fb1ba2b2d40>
```

Which can be used directly:

```
content(req[[1]]())
## [1] "allele\tseq_num\tstart\tend\tlength\tpeptide\tic50\tpercentile\trank\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t2\t10\t9\tLYNTVATLY\t1286.92\t1.3\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t4\t12\t9\tNTVATLYCV\t6061.08\t5.5\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t3\t11\t9\tYNTVATLYC\t27896.52\t21\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t8\t16\t9\tTLYCVHQRI\t36774.77\t24\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t5\t13\t9\tTVATLYCVH\t49607.80\t30\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t10\t18\t9\tYCVHQRIDV\t56565.29\t32\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t7\t15\t9\tATLYCVHQR\t83090.24\t39\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t1\t9\t9\tSLYNTVATL\t85418.12\t40\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t6\t14\t9\tVATLYCVHQ\t282195.45\t68\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t9\t17\t9\tLYCVHQRID\t491529.97\t79\n"
```

but can be converted to:

```
POST(url = "http://tools-cluster-interface.iedb.org/tools_api/mhci/",
     body = list(method = "smm",
                 sequence_text = "SLYNTVATLYCVHQRIDV",
                 allele = "HLA-A*01:01",
                 length = "9")) %>%
  content()
## [1] "allele\tseq_num\tstart\tend\tlength\tpeptide\tic50\tpercentile\trank\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t2\t10\t9\tLYNTVATLY\t1286.92\t1.3\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t4\t12\t9\tNTVATLYCV\t6061.08\t5.5\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t3\t11\t9\tYNTVATLYC\t27896.52\t21\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t8\t16\t9\tTLYCVHQRI\t36774.77\t24\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t5\t13\t9\tTVATLYCVH\t49607.80\t30\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t10\t18\t9\tYCVHQRIDV\t56565.29\t32\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t7\t15\t9\tATLYCVHQR\t83090.24\t39\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t1\t9\t9\tSLYNTVATL\t85418.12\t40\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t6\t14\t9\tVATLYCVHQ\t282195.45\t68\nHLA-A*01:01\t1\t9\t17\t9\tLYCVHQRID\t491529.97\t79\n"
```

And, you can get your data frame with:

```
library(readr)
library(httr)
library(magrittr)

POST(url = "http://tools-cluster-interface.iedb.org/tools_api/mhci/",
     body = list(method = "smm",
                 sequence_text = "SLYNTVATLYCVHQRIDV",
                 allele = "HLA-A*01:01",
                 length = "9")) -> res

content(res, as="text") %>%
  read_delim(delim="\t")
## # A tibble: 10 × 9
##         allele seq_num start   end length   peptide      ic50 percentile
##          <chr>   <int> <int> <int>  <int>     <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>
## 1  HLA-A*01:01       1     2    10      9 LYNTVATLY   1286.92        1.3
## 2  HLA-A*01:01       1     4    12      9 NTVATLYCV   6061.08        5.5
## 3  HLA-A*01:01       1     3    11      9 YNTVATLYC  27896.52       21.0
## 4  HLA-A*01:01       1     8    16      9 TLYCVHQRI  36774.77       24.0
## 5  HLA-A*01:01       1     5    13      9 TVATLYCVH  49607.80       30.0
## 6  HLA-A*01:01       1    10    18      9 YCVHQRIDV  56565.29       32.0
## 7  HLA-A*01:01       1     7    15      9 ATLYCVHQR  83090.24       39.0
## 8  HLA-A*01:01       1     1     9      9 SLYNTVATL  85418.12       40.0
## 9  HLA-A*01:01       1     6    14      9 VATLYCVHQ 282195.45       68.0
## 10 HLA-A*01:01       1     9    17      9 LYCVHQRID 491529.97       79.0
## # ... with 1 more variables: rank <chr>
```